# Change device name in wifidirect on android

Tags: android, wifi-direct

When I discover peers to connect to, i can fetch the list in this method:

```
@Override
public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
    List<WifiP2pDevice> peersList = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>(peers.getDeviceList());

}
```

WifiP2PDevice.deviceName returns the name set in the System Wifi settings on the WifiDirect page.

Lets say a user sets their nickname in my app to "John", is it possible to change the device name so when another device discovers it, the name will show up as "John"?

Comment: Do you mean inside the app?

Comment: @crazyPixel Yeah inside the app

Comment: Than why not save the nickname in sahredpreferences and expose the user as the nickname selected?

Comment: The default name would still be displayed for first time connections, but that is a nice work around for subsequent connections to the same device.

Comment: If it's an app to app thing than you can actually solve this problem to - create an interface that fire an onDiscoverD event once another user see you launch that event and send the details you want as a list - on the discovering user side create an interface with an onDiscover event and get the list of info - it's a bit more complicated to do than write (obiviously) but that should work pretty good...

Comment: @paulmcg did you manage to find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses hidden method. You can change the device name using the following code

```
Method m = manager.getClass().getMethod("setDeviceName", new Class[]     {channel.getClass(), String.class,
                    WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class});
        m.invoke(manager, channel, newDeviceName, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
            }
    });
```

Comment: this is i want @unrealsoul007, thnks, this answeR should be maRked as coRRect.